# ASP.NET WebAPI Selfhost didn't resolve route to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing with the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost" NuGet package in version "5.0.0-rc1" (tried also the current stable) but unfortunately I can't get my application setup to resolve the configured route to my implementation of the ApiController.

The application is quite simple and can be found nearly in all examples. It contains a .NET console application where in the main class the self host service lives.

```
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;
using System.Web.Http;
using System;
namespace EP.Server
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:60064");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default Route",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Server ist running on "+config.BaseAddress + " hit ENTER to stop.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and then there is a separate controller class which lives in the same project and inherits from the ApiController class.

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EP.Server
{
class UsersController : ApiController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello I'm a user...";
    }
}
}
```

The error message sounds like this when I call the service from any browser.

```
<Error>
<Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI   'http://localhost:60064/api/Users'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'Users'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Does somebody have an idea what's wrong there? Unfortunately I couldn't find any similar issues / questions on the web.

Thank you so far!

Comment: same thing here, however my controller is already *public* and the error persists... :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Web API controllers need to be **public**.

Comment: Ohhh boy, of course they should be and then everything works fine. Blame on me...

Comment: Hey Filip, thank you so far for your hint. It's quite funny because I was reading your howto from your blog and it's cool that you are answering. May I have another question? I've now extended my project in that way that I'm including services from external libraries. What I'd like to achieve now is that I would like set up new services without restarting my WebAPI core service. I'd like to check my AppConfig for new services and load them if they are requested. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to achive that yet. May you've a solution?